# Convergence in probability and almost surely when $X_n=n\mathbb{1}_{(n,n+1]}(X)$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

When a sequence of random variables $X_n$ is defined using $X_n=n\mathbb{1}_{(n,n+1]}(X)$, is it true that $X_n$ converges as to $X$? Or do they converge in probability?

I found this different from usual problems where $X_n=n\mathbb{1}_{(n,n+1]}(\omega)$, since the intuitive meaning of $\epsilon$ in $\lvert X_n-X\rvert\ge \epsilon$ is unclear. I think this should converge in prob but no a.s., as for some $\omega$ is $X$ is large, then $\lvert X_n-X\rvert$ could end up being close to at max 1.

How do I prove this mathematically?

Comment: For every $\omega$, the sequence $(X_n(\omega))$ does converge, but not necessarily to $X(\omega)$. Can you identify this pointwise limit?

Comment: @Did: Thanks for perusing this question. For your question, the answer is 0, I believe. For every $\omega$, there is a "step" for some $n$ and it is zero from thereon till infinity.

Comment: Exactly. So $X_n\to0$ almost surely, and this implies convergence in probability. Or one can check that $P(X_n\ne0)=P(n\lt X\leqslant n+1)\to0$, which implies convergence in probability.

Comment: @Did: I see the convergence to 0, but I need to prove $P(|X_n-X|\ge \epsilon)\to 0$. I am confused as to how to bring $X$ into the as and p convergence arguments.

Comment: But $P(|X_n-X|\geqslant\varepsilon)$ does not converge to $0$, $P(|X_n|\geqslant\varepsilon)$ does.

Comment: @Did: Ah, I have misread the problem, it was straightforward after all. Thanks for helping me out. If you could paste your comment as an answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: Maybe I'm dense, but what is $X$ here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $ω$, the sequence $(X_n(ω))$ does converge, but to $0$ hence not necessarily to $X(ω)$. Since $X_n→0$ almost surely, $X_n→0$ in probability.

Or, one can check that $P(X_n≠0)=P(n<X⩽n+1)→0$, which implies the convergence in probability.

Note finally that for every $ε\gt0$, $P(|X_n−X|⩾ε)$ does not necessarily converge to $0$, only $P(|X_n|⩾ε)$ does.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might help in this case to use $L^1(\Omega)$-convergence, just for convenience. Denote by $F^X(dx)$ the Law of $X$. Then

$$E[|X_n-X|] = E[|n\textbf{1}_{(n,n+1]}(X)-X|] = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|n\textbf{1}_{(n,n+1]}(x)-x|F^X(dx).$$

Does the above integral converge to 0?

Comment: Does it? If X is not integrable, every $E(|X_n-X|)$ is infinite.